# Swift: Правильный Deeplink для 2ГИС

Tags: swift, 2gis-api

Пытаюсь отправить координаты в 2ГИС приложение по следующему [руководству](https://help.2gis.ru/question/razrabotchikam-zapusk-mobilnogo-prilozheniya-2gis/ios), но ссылка оттуда просто не работает (пробую этот пример *dgis://2gis.ru/routeSearch/rsType/car/to/30.149939,59.849767* - открывается приложение и больше ничего не происходит). Попробовал другой вариант с *dgis://2gis.ru/search/координаты/* ищет только в том случае, если камера в приложении наведена на город, в котором находятся координаты (если отвести камеру от города, а потом попробовать перейти по ссылке, то перебросит в приложение, но координаты не подставятся и поиска не будет). Найти ответов по моему кейсу не удалось, поэтому хотелось бы узнать как корректно можно отправить координаты в 2ГИС приложение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй dgis://2gis.ru/geo/lon,lat

Вместо lon(долгота) и lat(широта) подставляются необходимые координаты.
Нужно обратить внимание на порядок указания координат, на 2gis и в большинстве случаев вообще пишется сначала широта, а потом долгота.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще то 2гис как я понял работает только в городах где по франшизе они есть как карта города. Одесса например работает ... Смотрите на сайте компании города где работает

Рабочий пример для Андроида.

```
            try {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("dgis://2gis.ru/routeSearch/rsType/car/from/"+MyLon+","+MyLat+"/to/"+longitude+","+latitude);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                intent.setPackage("ru.dublgis.dgismobile"); // Если не планируете работать с публичной бета-версией, эту строчку надо указать
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"set пavigation  market ");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=ru.dublgis.dgismobile"));
                activity.startActivity(intent);

            }
```